# jQuery prevent hide div if not hovered

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I got a site containing several divs (product-containers in a virtueemart-shop). They all have the same class and inside every div, there is a div called .togglecart.

I have this function; it shows this togglecart-div when hovering over the parent-div called .produktbox and hides it when hovering out:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if(!!('ontouchstart' in window)){
}
else {
    jQuery('.togglecart').hide();
    jQuery('.produktbox').hover(function() { 
        jQuery(this).children('.togglecart').show("slow"); 
    }, function() { 
        jQuery(this).children('.togglecart').hide("slow"); 
        });
    };
});
</script>
```

Inside the togglecart-div is the add-to-cart-button and a select/dropdownlist (add-to-cart-quantites to choose from). And of course this selectlist disappears when moving on it as it is not inside the area of .produktbox. I used selectpicker to transform the select-list into an ul li-dropdown menu. This prevents that this list disappears. But after selecting a value, the hovered togglecart-div including add-to-cart-button disappears. reason: the dropdown disappears after clicking on a value and then the mouse is below togglecart-div.

... got enough reputation points to post a pic now from local testserver:
[image: opened dropdown]

How could it be possible to prevent disappearing of togglecart-div after clicking a value?

Comment: Any chance you could make a fiddle with an example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is for the `.togglecart` divs to not hide when the checkbox inside is checked.

In that case, you could set a "hold" attribute to true on those divs whenever the checkbox is checked, and set to false when it is unchecked. Later when you hide your divs, you only do so if the attribute is not true.

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if(!!('ontouchstart' in window)){
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.togglecart[hold!="true"]').hide();
        jQuery('.produktbox').hover(function() { 
            jQuery(this).children('.togglecart').show("slow"); 
        }, function() { 
            jQuery(this).children('.togglecart[hold!="true"]').hide("slow"); 
        });
    };

    $(".mycheck").click(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $(this).parent().attr("hold", "true");
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().attr("hold", "false");
        }
    })
});
```

And jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Laj0u2re/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. There's no checkbox, but i'll try to use your input. Let you know more.

Comment: Right, should be fairly trivial to switch that out with a dropdownlist.